# Stripe Checkout, charge redirected to http://website/create_payment and the payment is not recorded in Stripe. What steps am I missing?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have embedded the stripe checkout code on my site, but at checkout, the site is redirected to website/create_payment and the payment is not recorded in Stripe. What steps am I missing? Here is the code I used from the Stripe documentation:

```
<form action="/create_payment" method="POST">
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key=
data-image="/square-image.png"
data-name="Demo Site"
data-description="2 widgets ($00.00)"
data-amount="0000"
data-currency="usd"
data-alipay-reusable="true"
data-locale="auto"
data-alipay="auto">
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: Usually this means something is wrong in your script that creates the charge from the card token. We'd need to see your code and any errors your can find.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  I recently added the code above to my original question.

Comment: So that part is Checkout. It only creates the card token, once it's done it redirects to what's in the `action` on the form where you need to create a charge. You can find more details here: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges

Comment: Many thanks. I am trying to see if I can use the Alipay integration using the Javascript API, but can't seem to find any relevant documentation. Would you happen to know if there a way to link to a custom button and add the Alipay commands as well?

Comment: Alipay is still in closed beta, you'd need to email stripe support to see if you can get access: https://support.stripe.com/email

Comment: Isn't the integration currently available via Checkout?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/guides/alipay-beta

Comment: This is a beta as written on the URL so not something supposed to be shared publicly :)